# How to test a presentation component using React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a `Tabs` component here.

[image]

Tabs.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Radio } from "antd";

function Tabs({ modes, selectedMode, handleChange }) {
  return (
    <Radio.Group onChange={handleChange} value={selectedMode}>
      {modes.map((opt) => (
        <Radio.Button key={opt.id} value={opt.id}>
          {opt.label}
        </Radio.Button>
      ))}
    </Radio.Group>
  );
}

export default Tabs;
```

App.jsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import Tabs from "./Tabs";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const MODES = [
  { id: 1, label: "Label 1" },
  { id: 2, label: "Label 2" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState(MODES[0]);

  const handleModeChange = (e) => {
    setMode(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Tabs modes={MODES} selectedMode={mode} handleChange={handleModeChange} />
  );
}
```

Here's the Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-tesla-tcj4p8

Currently I try to test for the `Tabs` component using Jest and React Testing Library.

There are 2 ways I can think of:

1. Test the styles change after user interaction

   ```
   describe('Tabs', () => {
     it('works correctly', () => {
       const MOCK_MODES = [
        { id: 1, label: "Label 1" },
        { id: 2, label: "Label 2" }
      ];
       const [mockSelected, setMockSelected] = useState(MOCK_MODES[0].id)
       const mockHandleModeChange = (e) => {
         setMode(e.target.value);
       };

       const { container, getByText } = render(<Tabs modes={MOCK_MODES} handleChange={mockHandleModeChange}/>);
       expect(container.firstChild).toHaveClass('ant-radio-button-wrapper-checked') 
       expect(container.secondChild).not.toHaveClass('ant-radio-button-wrapper-checked') 

       const item = getByText('Label 2');
       fireEvent.click(item);

       expect(container.firstChild).not.toHaveClass('ant-radio-button-wrapper-checked') 
       expect(container.secondChild).toHaveClass('ant-radio-button-wrapper-checked') 
     });
   });
   ```
2. Just check whether the `handleChange` event is fired, with black-box testing.

   ```
   describe('Tabs', () => {
     it('works correctly', () => {
       const MOCK_MODES = [
        { id: 1, label: "Label 1" },
        { id: 2, label: "Label 2" }
      ];
       const mockSelected = 1;
       const mockHandleModeChange = (e) => jest.fn();

       const { getByText } = render(<Tabs modes={MOCK_MODES} handleChange={mockHandleModeChange}/>);

       const item = getByText('Label 2');
       fireEvent.click(item);
       expect(mockHandleModeChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
     });
   });
   ```

Which one should be the best? Or any better suggestions?

Comment: I would avoid checking if the mocked event has been fired. Remember that RTL encourages you to assert what the user sees and does and wants you to avoid including implementation detail, which should be your laste resort.

Comment: @Fer Toasted thanks for the comment! Do you have real life example?

Comment: Think about what the responsibility of the thing you're testing is. It's to: 1. Show the appropriate thing based on the `selectedMode` prop; and 2. Invoke the `handleChange` prop callback with the appropriate value on interaction. So that's what you should test, which implies the `jest.fn()`. However I will say it's unclear from your example whether that _should_ be its responsibility (rather than actually _owning_ that piece of state) and I'd generally encourage _not_ giving one component (`Tabs`) uncontrolled access to change the state another component (`App`) by just giving it the setter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe because i am creating reusable Tabs component. That’s why I give it handleChange prop. How to “not giving uncontrolled access” In my case?

Comment: At its simplest, `handleChange={(value) => handleModeChange(value)}`. Now you can see `handleModeChange` is only directly called inside `App`. This gives `App` the opportunity to _check_ the `value`, e.g. _is_ that representative of a valid member in `MODES`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe got it. For the test case, is my second example better? Anything can be improved?

Comment: I think that's the correct approach, but evidently not everyone does. In terms of that test case, note what I said: _"Invoke the `handleChange` prop callback with the appropriate value based on interaction"_. Right now I'd say you **don't** actually cover that whole behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how can I cover the whole behaviour?